# Finding $\sqrt[4x]{x}$ assuming $x^{-81^{81^{-x}}}=81$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

**Question.**

> Suppose $\displaystyle x^{-81^{81^{-x}}}=81$. Find $\sqrt[4x]{x}$.

---

**Attempt.**

As far as I know, when we face this kind of problems in preparation for the university entrance exam in Latin America, we should take powers to a convenient value and try to resemble the exponents by their factors to look the same as the term in left.  For example, converting $$(ax)^x = a \Rightarrow (ax)^{ax}=a^a$$ Let us solve for $ax=a$, then $x=a^{a-1}$.  But I can't do that here.  I tried making it $A^A$, where $A=81^{-x}$, but the roles of exponent and base are interchanged in the problem, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Where does this task come from? (:

Comment: school list of problems

Comment: I meant the book.

Comment: not from a book, Teacher give us a paper with problems

Comment: I don't think powers of powers will help you because $(ax)^{x^a}\ne(ax)^{ax}$

Comment: I got something like $A^A = 81$ with $A = 1/81^x$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya $(3^2)^3 = 3^{2\times3}$. Be carefull, the second exponent multiplies the first

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya $(ax)^x$ to the power of $a$ is multiply $(ax)^x$ $a$ times, it means $\left\{(ax)^x\right\}^a = (ax)^{a\times x} = (ax)^{ax}$

Comment: $(ax)^{ax}=(ax)^{xa}$ I know that. The reason why I wrote $(ax)^{ax}$ was because the OP had that form. Besides, I wouldn' t call it $a$ _times_ because $a$ isn't necessarily an integer. When we talk about countable sets, we don't start with $|\mathbb Q|=|\mathbb N|$ although your point is here.

Comment: Totally agree. $a$ is not necessarily an integer. I through you mistake the power from his example with $(ax)^{x^a}$

Comment: $A^A=81$ is wrong

Comment: I think your question looks fine. You could ask for reopening this question here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34447/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$81^{-1} = x^{81^{81^{-x}}},$$

and hence

$${\left(81^{-1}\right)}^{81^{a}} = {\left(x^{\left(81^{81^{-x}}\right)}\right)}^{81^a} = x^{\left(81^{{81^{-x}}}\right)\cdot \left(81^a\right)} = x^{\displaystyle 81^{\left({81^{-x}}+a\right)}}.$$

Therefore, with $a = -81^{-x}$ we have

$${\left(81^{-1}\right)}^{81^{-81^{-x}}} = x^{81^0} = x,$$

or

$$x = 81^{-81^{-81^{-x}}}.\tag{$*$}$$

Substituting $x$ repeatedly in the expression above would gives us

$$x = 81^{-81^{-81^{-81^{\dots}}}}, \tag{1}$$

and if this made sense we could identify $x = 81^{-x}$.
It would then follow that $\sqrt[4x]{x} = \frac13$.

---

We can be more rigorous as follows.
Let $f:\Bbb R\longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be given by $f(t) = -(81^t)$.
Observe that $t = 81^{-t} \iff -t = -\left(81^{-t}\right) \iff -t$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Now, $f$ is a strictly decreasing function, and it's thus easy to see that it has a single fixed point.
We can rewrite equation $(*)$ as follows:

$$-x = -\left(81^{-\left(81^{-\left(81^{-x}\right)}\right)}\right) = f^3(-x),\tag{$**$}$$

so $-x$ is a fixed point of $f^3$.
Of course, the fixed point of $f$ is also a fixed point for $f^3$.

It remains to check that $f^3$ also has a single fixed point, from which it follows that $-x$ must be the fixed point of $f$.
This once again follows from the fact that $f^3$ is strictly decreasing; if this is not clear, it's a good exercise to look at how monotonicity behaves with compositions of strictly decreasing and strictly increasing functions.

We've shown hence that $x = 81^{-x}$, so that indeed $\sqrt[4x]{x} = \frac13$ as we had guessed before.

---

For what it's worth, $x = 81^{-x}$ has a solution in terms of Lambert's $W$, given by

$$x = \frac{W(\log(81))}{\log(81)}\approx 0.285360471863842099782478678983274970610868803768259$$

One can check that the approximation above 'satisfies' the equation

$$x^{-81^{81^{-x}}}=81$$

of the opening statement.

Comment: How does it follow that we can identify $x=81^{-x}$?

Comment: Consider equation $(1)$. The exponent $-81^{-81^{-81^{\dots}}}$ in the RHS is the negative of the entire RHS, that is, minus $x$.

Comment: I guess you assume that the right hand side of $(1)$ converges, i.e. that the previous equation has a solution?

Comment: @Servaes The solution should be much clearer now, and more basic even. I'm satisfied now.